# Git Private Server what http url to use to clone repository in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: linux, git, visual-studio-2015, centos7

With launch of Visual Studio 2015, we started looking for Git as source control. Being naive to linux, we tried and were able to install and configure the latest Git on our CentOS linux server using the tutorial below (option 2).

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7
```

we used the below article to create repository (testrepo) and do an initial commit successfully.

```
http://www.tecmint.com/install-git-to-create-and-share-your-own-projects-on-github-repository/
```

We now want to be able to push our commits to recently created repository from our remote server through visual studio 2015.

how do we come up with git url? what do we need to change or configure on our centos linux server?

**UPDATE**

git://user@serveripaddres:complete address to repository

did some more search and found the above format, but we are still unable to connect to the remote repository. Could anybody help?